# "Asymmetry" in the construction of products and coproducts in concrete categories

Tags: category-theory, soft-question, direct-product, coproduct

Mathematical objects like groups, vector spaces, topological spaces, etc. can be regarded as sets endowed with an additonal structure. The formal setting is that of a [concrete category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_category):

> A concrete category is a pair $(\mathbf C, \phi)$ such that $\mathbf C$ is a category  and $\phi : \mathbf C \to \mathbf{Set}$ (the category of sets and functions) is a faithful functor.
> The functor $\phi$ is to be thought of as a forgetful functor, which assigns to every object of $\mathbf C$ its "underlying set" and to every morphism in $\mathbf C$ its "underlying function".

Many standard examples like

- $\mathbf{G}$ = category of groups and homomorphisms
- $\mathbf{AG}$ = category of Abelain groups and homomorphisms
- $\mathbf{Vect}_F$ = category of vector spaces over a field $F$ and linear maps
- $\mathbf{Top}$ = category of topological spaces and continuous maps
- $\mathbf{Top_0}$ = category of pointed topological spaces and basepoint-preserving continuous maps

have products and coproducts. In all these examples the product $\prod_{i \in I} X_i$ of a family of objects $(X_i)_{i \in I}$ has the same underlying set - the Cartesian product of the underlying sets of the objects $X_i$.

This is not true for coproducts. In $\mathbf{G}$ it is the free product,  in $\mathbf{AG}$ and in $\mathbf{Vect}_F$ the direct sum, in $\mathbf{Top}$ the disjoint union and in $\mathbf{Top_0}$ the wedge. They have very different underlying sets; only for $\mathbf{Top}$ the underlying set is the disjoint sum of the underlying sets.

**Questions:**

1. Does this assymetric behavior with respect to underlying sets have a deeper reason or is it sheer coincidence?
2. Are there "natural" categories with products whose underlying sets are not the Cartesian products of underlying sets?

Of course the opposite categories of the above categories provide examples for 2., but I would not regard them as "natural" candidates for practical work.

Comment: Well, one way to explain it is that the forgetful functors have left adjoints.  But arguably that just pushes back the question to why they have left adjoints but not right adjoints.

Comment: For some of these, the extra data (besides the underlying set $X$) of an object comes in the form of maps $X^n\to X$ for some $n = 0,1,\dots$. Limits commuting yields a candidate for this data on the product set.

Comment: Wanted to note: It is most common to write $Ab$ for the category of abelian groups.

Comment: Just to emphasize: the notion of concrete category here might be misleading. It's really the forgetful functor having a left adjoint that matters. There's plenty of concrete categories where this isn't the case and the products are not given like this (some are in Daniël Apol's answer).

Comment: @Thorgott As you say, left adjointness ist the crucial point. But this is just a formal way to express the question. As Eric Wofsey comments, the question becomes "Why have the forgetful functors for the "basic" categories left adjoints, but no right adjoints?"

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/q/6376.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For all the algebraic examples $\mathscr{C}$, you could observe that they are all equivalent to some category $\mathrm{Fun}^\times(\mathscr{T},\mathsf{Set})$ of finite-product preserving functors, where $\mathscr{T}$ is the Lawvere theory of that algebraic structure. For each of the algebraic examples you list, there is an object $x\in\mathscr{T}$ for which the evaluation functor $\mathrm{ev}_x\colon\mathrm{Fun}^\times(\mathscr{T},\mathsf{Set})\to\mathrm{Set}$ corresponds to the forgetful functor $\mathscr{C}\to\mathsf{Set}$ under our chosen equivalence between $\mathscr{C}$ and $\mathrm{Fun}^\times(\mathscr{T},\mathsf{Set})$. But then it is not difficult to show that this forgetful functor preserves limits, but generally not all colimits.

If you accept that the forgetful functor $\mathsf{Top}\to\mathsf{Set}$ preserves limits, then it is general nonsense that the composite $\mathsf{Top}_{X/}\to\mathsf{Top}\to\mathsf{Set}$ does too, for any $X\in\mathsf{Top}$. This is because the forgetful maps $\mathscr{C}_{X/}\to\mathscr{C}$ and $\mathscr{C}_{/X}\to\mathscr{C}$ preserve limits respectively colimits, while they do not preserve general colimits respectively limits.

Since $\mathsf{Top}\to\mathsf{Set}$ also preserves all colimits, it isn't an example of the asymmetry, and the asymmetry in $\mathsf{Top}_*$ arises from taking the slice category $\mathsf{Top}_{*/}$, whereas taking an arbitrary overcategory would have made colimits be preserved while limits would be not preserved. (And overcategories are also generally interesting categories).

This brings us to examples of interesting categories where the underlying set of the product is not the product of the underlying sets. One example is $\mathrm{Top}_{/X}$ for $X\ncong *$, and generally categories consisting of ''bundles over a base object'' will be examples. I'd argue that these are genuinely interesting categories.

Another example in a similar spirit is the category of schemes, where the underlying set is the underlying set of the locally ringed space associated to the scheme. You might argue that schemes are closely related to $\mathsf{CRing}^\mathrm{op}$ and therefore it may not count, but when restricted to affine schemes the forgetful functor to sets is genuinely different than the forgetful functor you'd get if you'd *define* affine schemes to be objects in the category $\mathsf{CRing}^\mathrm{op}$, so this is a nontrivial example.