On the fundamental difference between left and right adjoints
On p. 116 of her Category Theory in Context, Emily Riehl writes (my emphasis):

In §4.5, we prove what is perhaps the most frequently applied result in category theory: that right adjoint functors preserve limits while left adjoint functors preserve colimits. This explains why limits tend to be easier to construct than the formally dual colimit notions.

I find the last sentence puzzling, because it seems to suggest that left and right adjoints are not as symmetrical notions as they appear to me, and that there is a fundamental difference between them that I am not able perceive.
I would appreciate it if someone could flesh out why the result about left and right adjoints that Riehl cites explains the difference she alludes to between limits and colimits.

EDIT:
After thinking some more about it, I have come up with a slightly more formal way to express my confusion.
Let $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ be two categories, and let $L:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ and $R:\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{C}$ be functors.  If $$\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(c, R(d)) \cong \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{D}}(L(c), d)$$
is natural for all $c \in \text{Obj}(\mathcal{C})$, $d\in\text{Obj}(\mathcal{D})$, then we say that $L$ is the left-adjoint of $R$, and $R$ is the right-adjoint of $L$.
In this case, we also have the induced functors $L^\text{op}:\mathcal{C^\text{op}}\to\mathcal{D}^\text{op}$ and $R^\text{op}:\mathcal{D}^\text{op}\to\mathcal{C}^\text{op}$.
Now, in general, $$\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(c, c')\cong \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}^\text{op}}(c', c) \\
\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{D}}(d, d')\cong \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{D}^\text{op}}(d', d)$$
Therefore, we also have that $$\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{D}^\text{op}}(d, L^\text{op}(c)) \cong \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}^\text{op}}(R^\text{op}(d), c),$$
for all $c \in \text{Obj}(\mathcal{C}^\text{op})$, $d\in\text{Obj}(\mathcal{D}^\text{op}).$  Furthermore, one can show that this isomorphism is natural, since the original natural isomorphism $\eta:\text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(-, R(-))\Rightarrow\text{Hom}_\mathcal{D}(L(-), -)$ induces an natural isomorphism $\eta^\text{op}: \text{Hom}_\mathcal{C^\text{op}}(R^\text{op}(-), -)\Rightarrow\text{Hom}_\mathcal{D^\text{op}}(-, L^\text{op}(-))$.  More specifically, for every $\alpha^\text{op}\in\text{Hom}_\mathcal{C^\text{op}}(R^\text{op}(d), c)$, $\eta^\text{op}(\alpha^\text{op})$ is defined to be $(\eta(\alpha))^\text{op}$.1
In this case, $R^\text{op}$ is the left-adjoint of $L^\text{op}$, and $L^\text{op}$ is the right-adjoint of $R^\text{op}$.
All this is to spell out, in truly excruciating detail, why it strikes me as odd that there is a qualititative difference between left- and right-adjointness, since for every left-adjoint functor $L$ there is a formally entirely analogous right-adjoint functor $L^\text{op}$ between some other two categories out there, and I would expect that $L^\text{op}$ would exhibit all the qualitative features of $L$.  And similarly, of course, for $R^\text{op}$ with respect to $R$.

1Sorry, I fear that I may be abusing notation here.  In the last sentence above, I have tacked an $^\text{op}$ after elements of hom-sets $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(-, -)$ and $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{D}}(-, -)$ to express the isomorphisms $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(c, c')\cong \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}^\text{op}}(c', c)$ and $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{D}}(d, d')\cong \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{D}^\text{op}}(d', d)$ alluded to earlier.  Thus, by $\alpha^\text{op}$ I mean the element of $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}^\text{op}}(R^\text{op}(d), c)$ that corresponds to $\alpha\in\text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(c, R(d))$ under the first of these isomorphisms, and by $(\eta(\alpha))^\text{op}$ I mean the element of $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{D}^\text{op}}(d, L^\text{op}(c))$ that corresponds to $\eta(\alpha)\in\text{Hom}_\mathcal{D}(L(c), d)$ under the second.

It's simply because reality (ahem) is not symmetric. In practice forgetful functors are right adjoints much more often than left adjoints. Just check a few examples yourself.

@ZhenLin: What you say may be true, but it does not sound to me like what Riehl is saying.  At least I don't see it...

I'm not convinced that the explanation flows in that direction. One might equally claim that limits are more natural than colimits (e.g. there is a natural formula for limits in sets that has no obvious equivalent for colimits) and that this explains why forgetful functors are often right adjoints, or something.

If you're just confused about the explanation in either direction, remember that left/right adjoints can be defined in terms of initial/terminal objects in comma categories, while colimits/limits can be defined as left/right adjoints to the diagonal functor.

Limits are indeed more natural. I would even say they are more fundamental. Enriched category theory proves this: everything is reduced to limits in the base category.

@ZhenLin Probably the conceptional reason is that the categories are defined as models of essential algebraic theories and not as coalgebraic theories.

A way to express in simple words what @MartinBrandenburg and ZhenLin said is that a limit is about solving an equation (${x\mid f(x)=g(x)}$); a colimit is about identifying elements under an equivalence relation. The former procedure is algorithmic ("solve $x^2+3x+2=0$"), the latter procedure most of the time can't be made concrete (you quotient a set $X$ by the equivalence relation generated by a subset $R\subseteq X\times X$ of $X$, the transitive closure can be characterized, but rarely computed fully explicitly).

For the special case of products and coproducts also see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4845781/349785.

@fosco: Thank you!  Your comment is the only one that (a) I can begin to follow, AND (b) attempts to characterize the fundamental qualitative difference between left and right adjoints.  I think it may be the seed for an answer to my question, especially if it is accompanied by an example illustrating it.

@fosco: One more thing: something that still confuses me about your comment is that I thought that a colimit is "just a limit in the opposite category", or something like that.  If so, then every limit is also a colimit (somewhere), so I have a hard time seeing why it is more algorithmic in the original category than in its opposite.

The opposite of the category of sets is not the category of sets.

@NaïmFavier: Yes but it is a category.  (Sorry, I guess I don't get your point.)

fosco and I are making the same point in different words: limits in the category of sets are easier to express than colimits. The formal duality of category theory that swaps limits and colimits does not extend to the category of sets.

Some of the comments might make good answers...

@kjo the opposite of a category $\mathbf{NaturalThings}$ is rarely a category of natural things, more likely it's a category of the form $\mathbf{WeirdStuff}$. Sometimes it's not (there's a neat characterization of $Set^{op}$: it's the category of complete atomic Boolean algebras. But this is a nontrivial result), and when it is the case we call the identification $A^{op}\cong B$ as "X duality", where X is the name of the mathematician who discovered this characterization.

@fosco: I can't say that I can follow your reasoning there.  Maybe I just don't know enough category theory (or math) for me to see your point.  Be that as it may, I edited my original post to spell out more formally the source of my confusion.

The more your question unravels, the more it seems to me that your confusion relates to adjoint functors only tangentially, and in fact it's more about the concept of the opposite category.
Since "one of the more mysterious bits of structure possessed by the 2-category $\bf Cat$" is the functor $(\_)^{op}$ sending a category $\mathcal C$ to its opposite, I don't find your question naive, and I believe we should try to dispel a few false beliefs about how exactly $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal C^{op}$ relate precisely. I have seen such false beliefs in many students (heck, I have held myself a lot of false beliefs about duality until not long ago, and I can't say I solved them all), so you're definitely not alone.
The fundamental take-home of all this discussion is that

The fact that $\mathcal C$'s morphisms admit a concrete description does not imply that $\mathcal C^{op}$'s morphisms do admit one as well.


The (true) fact that a co-trundletop in $\mathcal C$ is just a trundletop in $\mathcal C^{op}$ should not be confused with the (false) fact that trundletops and co-trundletops bear any expressible resemblance when you write them down "in formulas".

A starting point to better frame this issue is to think very hard about what the duality principle in category theory means:

(Borceux, book 1)
The details in this statement are important: if you remove "in every category", it's false. If you change what "dual statement" means, it's false. A statement expressed in the language of category theory has to be dualized entirely and correctly in order to yield a valid statement. (This might appear a "well, duh" kind of truism, but it's a pitfall many students -and adult mathematicians- fall into all the time!)
I'll give you an example of something highly false that I believed for the first few months after my first exposition to category theory: one can prove that (say, in the category of sets)
$$ \hom(\varinjlim X_i,Y)\cong \varprojlim \hom(X_i,Y)\qquad \hom(X,\varprojlim Y_i)\cong\varprojlim\hom(X,Y_i)$$
"But then", said fouche not without a certain presumption, "it must be also that
$$\hom(\varprojlim X_i,Y)\cong \varinjlim \hom(X_i,Y)\qquad \hom(X,\varinjlim Y_i)\cong\varinjlim\hom(X,Y_i)$$
by duality!"
Now, coming to your question: you seem confused by the fact that limits (subobjects of a product) and colimits (quotients of a coproducts) do not look like one is obtained from the other by dualizing the structure of its definition. Meaning: why is the notion of subset dual to the notion of quotient? For this, it seems the answers you're getting feel relatively unsatisfactory. It is understandable, as it's another step of learning we've all been through. My answer is: do not confuse the fact that the notion of a limit is completely dual to the notion of a colimit, with the [false] fact that as a consequence [the inference is not true!] we should be able to compute a colimit $X=\varinjlim X_i$ of a diagram by feeding a machinery that, without fail, spits out $X$ out of an input limit $X^*=\varprojlim X_i^*$.
This is simply not the case, it doesn't happen: for example limits are often easy (but there are counterexamples to this in non-algebraic categories, I'll give you one below), and colimits are often awfully hard to describe explicitly, in all categories $\cal A$ of algebraic structures. There is a technical reason for this, that you will discover when/if you encounter the theory of monads; but for the time being, suffices to say that we know very well that this happens for a well-understood property of the functor $U : \mathcal A \to Set$ that forgets all the operations on a set prescribed by the structure signature that defines $\cal A$ $(A,\{\dots,op'ns,\dots\})$, and gives the underlying set $A$.
For example, define a zibble to be a nonempty set $A$ with a quaternary operation (called the zib map) $z : A\times A\times A\times A \to A$ such that $z(x_{\sigma 1},x_{\sigma 2},x_{\sigma 3},x_{\sigma 4}) = z(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ for every $x_i\in A$, and a distinguished element $a_0\in A$ such that $z(a_0,a_0,a_0,a_0)=a_0$. The product of two zibbles is easy to describe in terms of the cartesian product of the carrier sets, and the equalizer of two zibble homomorphisms (defined in the most evident way) is also easy to describe as the equalizer of their underlying functions.
But there is no way to deduce what the coproduct of two zibbles is in terms of the disjoint union of the carrier sets: defining the sum zib $z_{A+B} : (A+B)^4\to A+B$ means to define

two maps, respectively of type $A^4\to A$ and $B^4\to B$ -easy: the zibs on $A$ and $B$ you started with.
four maps of type $A^3\times B\to A+B$, and four of type $A\times B^3\to B$
six maps of type $A^2\times B^2\to A+B$.

...and taking all these maps together, you must then impose the zibble axioms. Where should the zib of two elements in $A$ with two elements in $B$ belong? To $A$ or to $B$? Why the one, why not the other?
Clearly there is an answer to this problem: a coproduct, whatever it is, satisfies a universal property that characterizes it completely and unequivocally. Imposing that universal property is what makes you sure that you're constructing the right object, no matter how complicated.
Let me turn to a more familiar kind of structure than zibbles now, monoids: coproducts of monoids pose the exact same problem: when you want to sum two monoids $M$ and $N$ together, you also need to decide where the product of $m\in M$ and $n\in N$ goes, and there is no canonical choice for it, why should I prefer $m.n\in M$ over $m.n\in N$? Instead, $m.n$ is a new kind of thing, obtained from a formal irreducible expression $\texttt{mn}$ (literally: I mean the meaningless string of characters obtained juxtaposing the meaningless symbol $\texttt{m}$ with the meaningless symbol $\texttt{n}$) by quotienting under the monoid axioms (and only under the monoid axioms: the coproduct $M+N$ of monoids is called free because no equation that doesn't directly follow from the monoid axioms can hold in $M+N$).
Colimits, however, are easy in other categories, the coalgebraic ones:

let $\mathcal C$ be any nonempty category, fix an object $C\in \cal C$. Colimits in the slice category ${\cal C}/C$ of morphisms with codomain $C$ are computed exactly as they are computed in $\cal C$.

Fix two nonempty sets $A,B$. Define the category ${\cal M}(A,B)$ having objects the triples $(E,d,s)$ where $E$ is a set, $d : A\times E\to E$ and $s : E\to B$ are functions. A homomorphism $(E,d,s)\to (F,p,q)$ is a function $h : E\to F$ such that $p\circ (A\times h) = h\circ d$ and $q\circ h=s$ (draw the diagrams!).
Colimits in ${\cal M}(A,B)$ are computed exactly like in $Set$: prove
it. The terminal object of ${\cal M}(A,B)$ is an object $(T,d_!,s_!)$
where $T$ is an infinite set (of cardinality $\max\{|A|,\aleph_0\}$),
whose elements are... describe them!



I enjoy these attempts at impromptu teaching.. I hope I didn't overload you!

Thank you for this.  Yes, you did overload me, but that is not a bad thing.  Would you mind explaining the $\varinjlim$/$\varprojlim$ notation?

Also, I now realize I was wrong to locate my confusion in the concepts of adjoints; it is rather in the concepts of limit and colimit, and more specifically, in the idea that "limits are easy, colimits are hard."  I also realize, however, thanks to your and @Thorgott's answer, as well as to some of the comments, that this apparent asymmetry between limits and colimits (surprising as it is in light of the $\mathcal{C}$/$\mathcal{C}^\text{op}$ duality) may be more an artefact of history/praxis than something that can be formally proven in any way.  This is maybe the seed for another question.

You are correct in observing that if $L\colon\mathcal{C}\leftrightarrows\mathcal{D}\colon R$ is an adjunction, then so is $R^{op}\colon\mathcal{D}^{op}\leftrightarrows\mathcal{C}^{op}\colon L^{op}$. Thus, the concept of a left adjoint is 'formally dual' to that of a right adjoint by 'inverting the arrows' (in the same way the concept of a colimit is dual to the concept of a limit, etc.).
The point Emily Riehl is making here, however, is not of a formal nature, but of a practical nature. And, in mathematical praxis, you want to understand the usual constructions in a specific category. If I have to understand a colimit in the category $\mathrm{Grp}$ of groups (and understanding such colimits is the same thing as understanding groups in terms of generators and relations, which is infamously difficult), then pointing out that's equivalent to understanding a limit in $\mathbf{Grp}^{op}$ is not actually helpful. Indeed, as noted in the comments, the opposite category of a nice category you are interested is oftentimes a not-so-nice category. The observation now is that most of the usual examples of categories are concrete categories, i.e. categories $\mathcal{C}$ equipped with a sort of 'forgetful functor' $\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathbf{Set}$ that is faithful. These functors are very often right adjoints and much less often left adjoints. The "Why?" to that observation is a philosophical question—some explanations were offered in the comments, others can be found on MO—, but that's what the remark is about.

Small correction. In many cases, dual categories of nice categories are still nice to some extent, but more complex and more geometric in nature. For example, the dual of the category of abelian groups is the category of compact abelian topological groups (by Pontryagin duality). Also, the dual of the category of commutative rings is the category of affine schemes. The list goes on. But yes I don't know about the category of groups. Perhaps I will ask a separate q.

A perspective is to consider $\mathrm{Rel}$, the category of relations of sets, as fundamental. $\mathrm{Rel}$ is a dagger category, so its morphisms are essentially undirected. The category $\mathrm{Set}$ is the subcategory of morphisms that are

right-unique: every element of the domain has at most one image
left-total: every element of the domain has at least one image

In other words, functions. The reason we care about this property is subjective, but in my opinion, it is because of the philosophical fundamentality of the arrow of time. With every composition we intuit a small passage of time, and we expect that the "next" state will be valid and unambiguous. Thus we gravitate towards functions and their inherent assymetry that mimics the asymmetry of time evolution.
Since we implicitly operate in this left-total, right-unique context, we imbue our mathematical statements with an inherent "flow". Predicates that go with this flow will be easy to work with, because they will cohere with the current context; and predicates that go against this flow will be hard to work with, because they require going back and reconsidering things.
More precisely, going with the flow means that we can turn directed structure into undirected (commutative) structure:

$p \implies (q \implies r)$ is logically equivalent to $p \wedge q \implies r$

$(p \implies q) \implies r$ is not reducible


This has a precise analogy in Set in terms of the tensor-hom adjunction. A vivid consequence of this is the difference between $3^{(3^{(3^{3})})}$ and $(3^3)^3)^3$ - the former is massive, the latter is just $3^{27}$.
This is reductive, but it pays to think of every adjunction as being an an analogue of the tensor-hom adjunction: a statement that we have an equivalence between a functor going with the flow (hom, right adjoint) and a functor not interacting with the flow (tensor, left adjoint). Thus, we should expect the functor that aligns with the flow to be easier to work with than the functor that tries to escape the flow. (In practice, of course, the tensor product doesn't need to be commutative)
